# Xamarin : using native libraries exception received

Tags: android, mono, xamarin.android, xamarin

So I am new to Xamarin and android development , i have created a shared library that is written in C++ , compiled under armv7eabi (using Atollic GCC) , but i am having issues using the shared library ,and hopefully someone here can help me :

The name of the library is libtstcpp.so  , i put it under lib/armeabi ,set it as androidnativelibrary, i did DLL import like this

[DllImport("tstcpp" , EntryPoint = "_Z10GetCounterv")] public extern static int GetCounter();

int test = GetCounter();

it worked at first ,and i recived the value , but when i renamed the name of the shared library (and everything else related) i recive dll not found exception .

The same problem occured when i added another shared library , it also says that dll not found .

I understand that maybe (?!?) the library is not download with the application to the device ? if so , how can i fix the issue ? ( I am using Xamarin studio).

Comment: Hi , Actually i discovered that i am getting the dll not found exception because my shared library is consists of many *.o files ,but why ? does anyone know ?